# How to load image from disk to vmem

Tags: assembly, kernel, osdev, fasm, video-memory

I am writing an OS in fasm assembly and I faced with problem. I was trying to draw font pixel-by-pixel, but it is too hard and strange. I want to make bitmap pixel-by-pixel font and save it on hdd, and in kernel code make function, that can load it to video memory. I tried to google it, but without success. Help, please

Code of kernel:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Macroses
macro rect c, x, y, w, h {
    pusha
    mov bx, c
    mov cx, x
    mov dx, y
    mov si, w
    mov di, h
    call __rect
    popa
}
macro pixel c, x, y {rect c, x, y, 1, 1}
macro __video__init {
    pusha
    ;mov ax, 0x4F02
    ;mov bx, 0x101
    ;int 0x10
    mov   ah,     0x00
    mov   al,     0x13
    int   0x10
    rect  0x00,   0,      0,     640*2,   480*2
    popa
}
macro sym c, x, y, s {
    pusha
    xor bx, bx
    mov bx, c
    mov cx, x
    mov dx, y
    mov al, s
    call __sym
    popa
}
macro image x, y, w, h, addr {
    pusha
    mov si, x
    mov di, y
    mov [reg0], w
    mov [reg8], h
    mov bp, addr
    popa
}
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Cosmetics
macro return value {
    mov eax, value
ret
}
macro far a {
    mov ax, a/16
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mul ax, 16
    mov sp, ax
    div ax, 16
    jmp ax:0x0000
}
macro rint trr {
    pusha
    mov bp, trr
    cmp bp, 0x10
    popa
    je __r10h
}
macro retn {ret}
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Tests
macro __video__test {
    sym 0x0F, 0x00, 0x00, '!'
    sym 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x00, '"'
    sym 0x0F, 0x20, 0x00, '#'
    sym 0x0F, 0x30, 0x00, '$'
    sym 0x0F, 0x40, 0x00, '%'
    sym 0x0F, 0x50, 0x00, '&'
    sym 0x0F, 0x60, 0x00, "'"
    sym 0x0F, 0x70, 0x00, '('
    sym 0x0F, 0x80, 0x00, ')'
    sym 0x0F, 0x90, 0x00, '*'
    sym 0x0F, 0xA0, 0x00, '+'
    sym 0x0F, 0xB0, 0x00, ','
    sym 0x0F, 0xC0, 0x00, '-'
    sym 0x0F, 0xD0, 0x00, '.'
    sym 0x0F, 0xE0, 0x00, '/'
    sym 0x0F, 0xF0, 0x00, '0'
    sym 0x0F, 0x100,0x00, '1'
    image 0, 0, 320, 200, 0
    call __frame
}
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Kernel
__kernel:
    org 0x7E00
    mov [bootdev], dl
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Grafic Core
    __video__init
    ;rect 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x280, 0x190
    __video__test

    jmp $
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Bss
    buffer     db 1024 dup (?)
    bootdev    db 0x00
    reg0       db 0x0000
    reg1       db 0x0000
    hexstr     db '0x0000', 0x00
    rstr       db "Talisman's R-OS 0.0.1a", 0x00
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Funcs
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Bitmap font func
__sym:
    cmp al, '!'
    je .!
    cmp al, '"'
    je ."
    cmp al, '#'
    je .sharp
    cmp al, '$'
    je .dollar
    cmp al, '%'
    je .%
    cmp al, '&'
    je .et
    cmp al, "'"
    je .'
    cmp al, '('
    je .brt
    cmp al, ')'
    je .brt2
    cmp al, '*'
    je .star
    cmp al, '+'
    je .plus
    cmp al, ','
    je .comma
    cmp al, '-'
    je .menos
    cmp al, '.'
    je .point
    cmp al, '/'
    je .slash
    cmp al, '0'
    je .0
    cmp al, '1'
    je .1
    retn
.!:
    add cx, 3
    add dx, 4
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 5
    add dx, 7
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    retn
.":
    add cx, 2
    add dx, 3
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 3
    add cx, 3
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 3
    retn
.sharp:
    add cx, 2
    add dx, 4
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 8
    add cx, 3
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 8
    sub cx, 4
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 7, 1
    add dx, 4
    rect bx, cx, dx, 7, 1
    retn
.dollar:
    add cx, 3
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    dec cx
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 4, 1
    dec cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    add cx, 4
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    sub cx, 3
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    add cx, 2
    add dx, 1
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    inc cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    sub cx, 4
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    inc cx
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 4, 1
    inc cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    retn
.%:
    inc cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    dec cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 2
    add cx, 3
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 2
    sub cx, 2
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    dec cx
    add dx, 5
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    sub cx, 2
    add dx, 7
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    dec cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 2
    add cx, 3
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 2
    sub cx, 2
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    retn
.et:
    add cx, 2
    add dx, 3
    rect bx, cx, dx, 3, 1
    dec cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2 ,2
    add cx, 3
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    sub cx, 2
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 3, 1
    dec cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 4
    add cx, 3
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 4, 1
    inc cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    sub cx, 3
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 3, 1
    add cx, 4
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    retn
.':
    add cx, 3
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 3
    retn
.brt:
    add cx, 5
    add dx, 2
    pixel bx, cx, dx
    dec cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    dec cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    dec cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    inc cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    inc cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    inc cx
    inc dx
    pixel bx, cx, dx
    retn
.brt2:
    add cx, 3
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 2
    ;inc cx
    ;inc dx
    ;rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 2
    inc cx
    inc dx
    pixel bx, cx, dx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    inc cx
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    dec cx
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    ;dec cx
    inc dx
    ;rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    dec cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 1
    inc dx
    pixel bx, cx, dx
    retn
.star:
    add cx, 3
    add dx, 3
    pixel bx, cx, dx
    sub cx, 2
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 5, 1
    inc cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 3, 1
    inc dx
    pixel bx, cx, dx
    add cx, 2
    pixel bx, cx, dx
    retn
.plus:
    add cx, 3
    add dx, 5
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 5
    sub cx, 2
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 6, 1
    retn
.comma:
    add cx, 3
    add dx, 10
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    inc cx
    add dx, 2
    pixel bx, cx, dx
    retn
.menos:
    inc cx
    add dx, 7
    rect bx, cx, dx, 6, 1
    retn
.point:
    add cx, 3
    add dx, 10
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 2
    retn
.slash:
    add dx, 9
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    inc cx
    dec dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    retn
.0:
    inc cx
    add dx, 3
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 10
    add cx, 4
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 10
    dec cx
    inc dx
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    dec cx
    add dx, 5
    rect bx, cx, dx, 1, 3
    dec cx
    sub dx, 7
    rect bx, cx, dx, 4, 1
    add dx, 11
    rect bx, cx, dx, 4, 1
    retn
.1:
    add cx, 4
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 2, 10
    sub cx, 2
    add dx, 2
    rect bx, cx, dx, 3, 2
    add dx, 6
    rect bx, cx, dx, 6, 2
    retn
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  fast putpix func
__rect:
    push    ds    dx       di
    imul    dx,   320
    add dx,   cx
    mov ax,   0xA000
    mov ds,   ax
    jmp ._o
._o:
    push    si
    jmp ._i
._i:
    dec si
    mov byte  [edx+esi],       bl;bx
    jnz ._i
    pop si
    add dx,   320
    dec di
    jnz ._o
    pop di    dx       ds
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Image func
__image:
    mov ah, 0x00
    int 0x13
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, [reg8]
    imul al, 320
    add al, 0x8700
    add al, [reg0]
    idiv al, 512
    mov bx, 0x8700+si+320*di
    mov es, 0x00
    mov ch, 0x00
    mov cl, (bp+512+0x7FFF-64000)/512
    mov dh, 0x00
    mov dl, [bootdev]
    int 0x13
    ret
__frame:
    mov ebx, 0x00000000
._l:
    mov byte [ebx+0xA000], [ebx+0x8700]
    cmp ebx, 6400
    je ._r
    jmp ._l
._r:
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  R interrupts
__r10h:
    sym bx, cx, dx, al
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  Footer
__footer:
    cli
    hlt
    jmp $-2
    times 0x7FFF-64000-$+$$ db 0x00
```

I hope my code will be more optimized in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't make head nor tails about your *__image* code! You have thrown together a bunch of instructions that FASM wouldn't even be able to assemble.

And **why would you load a font, or image, or any other file from disk when you don't have a file system that you can use**? For now, all you can do is embed the character set in the kernel that your 1st stage bootloader has loaded into memory.

This is wrong: In your *__video__init* macro, where you setup the 320x200 256-color video mode, the black filled rectangle (`rect 0x00, 0, 0, 640*2, 480*2`) that you draw is much too large, and frankly you don't need it since setting the video mode will already have blackend the screen.

### A bitmapped solution

To start using a bitmapped font, you'll have to define a character set in your program. Below is a very incomplete example of a character set where each character is 8 pixels wide and 12 pixels height. I have included the bit patterns for the digit "0" and the capitals "A" and "B".

```
CharSet12:
    times (48 * 12) db 0                                         ; 0 -> 47
    db 0, 124, 198, 198, 198, 214, 214, 198, 198, 198, 124, 0    ; 48 = Char "0"
    times (16 * 12) db 0                                         ; 49 -> 64
    db 0, 16, 56, 108, 198, 198, 254, 198, 198, 198, 198, 0      ; 65 = Char "A"
    db 0, 252, 102, 102, 102, 124, 102, 102, 102, 102, 252, 0    ; 66 = Char "B"
    times (189 * 12) db 0                                        ; 67 -> 255
```

You can design your own fonts this way and select any width and height that you like.

### Drawing transparent text

In transparent text, you only plot pixels that have the foreground color.
The background shines through. Next code does that:

```
; IN (al,bl,cx,dx) OUT () MOD (ax)
DrawTransparentCharacter:
    push    es cx si di
    mov     ah, 12          ; OffsetInCharacterSet = CharacterHeight * ASCII
    mul     al
    mov     si, ax
    imul    di, dx, 320     ; OffsetInVideoMemory = (Y * 320) + X
    add     di, cx
    mov     ax, 0xA000
    mov     es, ax
    mov     ch, 12          ; CharacterHeight
.OuterLoop:
    mov     cl, 8           ; CharacterWidth
    mov     al, [CharSet12 + si]
.InnerLoop:
    shl     al, 1
    jnc     .Skip
    mov     [es:di], bl     ; Plot pixel
.Skip:
    inc     di
    dec     cl
    jnz     .InnerLoop
    inc     si              ; To next font byte
    add     di, 320 - 8     ; To next scanline
    dec     ch
    jnz     .OuterLoop
    pop     di si cx es
    ret
```

Now you can output a character anywhere on the screen based on the pixel position of its upperleft corner.

```
; This draws a light green "A" in the middle of the screen
mov     dx, 94      ; Y
mov     cx, 156     ; X
mov     bl, 10      ; Color LightGreen
mov     al, 65      ; "A"
call    DrawTransparentCharacter
```

### Drawing opaque text

In opaque text, you not only plot pixels that have the foreground color, but also those that make up the background rectangle. Next code does that:

```
; IN (al,bx,cx,dx) OUT () MOD (ax)
DrawOpaqueCharacter:
    push    es cx dx si di
    mov     ah, 12          ; OffsetInCharacterSet = CharacterHeight * ASCII
    mul     al
    mov     si, ax
    imul    di, dx, 320     ; OffsetInVideoMemory = (Y * 320) + X
    add     di, cx
    mov     ax, 0xA000
    mov     es, ax
    mov     ch, 12          ; CharacterHeight
.OuterLoop:
    mov     cl, 8           ; CharacterWidth
    mov     al, [CharSet12 + si]
.InnerLoop:
    mov     dl, bl          ; Foreground color
    shl     al, 1
    jc      .Plot
    mov     dl, bh          ; Background color
.Plot:
    mov     [es:di], dl     ; Plot pixel
    inc     di
    dec     cl
    jnz     .InnerLoop
    inc     si              ; To next font byte
    add     di, 320 - 8     ; To next scanline
    dec     ch
    jnz     .OuterLoop
    pop     di si dx cx es
    ret
```

Now you can output a character anywhere on the screen based on the pixel position of its upperleft corner.

```
; This draws a green on bright white "B" in the bottom right corner of the screen
mov     dx, 188     ; Y
mov     cx, 312     ; X
mov     bx, 0x0F02  ; Colors GreenOnBrightWhite
mov     al, 66      ; "B"
call    DrawOpaqueCharacter
```

Comment: I understood that I made a lot of helpless actions, but let's think that font placed in hdd without fs, without title. just tuple of bytes. and i wanna copy bytes from hdd to video buffer. it's all. thanks for advices